# How to add Firebase pre-built Auth UI for flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, flutter-web

How to implement Firebase built ui into a flutter web app? I've seen many tutorials but all of them implement google sign in. There is this firebase page that teaches you how to implement this ui in web but it's so confusing and even more if you are new to Flutter, Dart and Web development and after all, does it even support flutter web apps?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it may technically be possible to integrate FirebaseUI auth sign ins into Flutter for web, I doubt it'll be a smooth integration.

FirebaseUI comes with a sign-in UI for use in traditional DOM based web apps. But Flutter for Web is not a traditional web UI, as it actually renders its output in Web GL instead of traditional DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

While @Frank is absolutely right you might want to try the following flutter package which has done the UI work and is available for Web also.

**Note:-** It is not official and I have never used it. Just suggesting.

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth_ui

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the package https://pub.dev/packages/faui.
It implements Firebase authentication UI on top of Firebase API and is platform agnostic.

This is the demo: https://flatter-auth-ui-demo1.codemagic.app/#/